# Finding multiple strings in a text file python

Tags: python, pandas, file, io

I have a data frame which consists of a list of strings (actual data set contains a list of 1000s of strings). I'm trying to search through a text file to see if any of those strings are in the text file and return the file name and that string.

```
data = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Fruit'])
```

output to look like

```
File Name |  String
1.txt     |  Apple
1.txt     |  Orange
```

i'm just trying to do it with one file right now and then I can add in the multiple files

```
string_list = df['Fruit'].values
file_name = '1.txt'

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for word in (line.strip() for line in f):
       if word in string_list:
           print(file_name, word)
```

However nothing is being returned. Can anyone help? There are some strings which are multiple words which is wher I think my logic is wrong but not sure how to fix

Comment: What is the purpose of `string_list = df['Fruit'].values`, couldn't you just have an array?

Comment: `string_list` is not a string, so I don't think you can use `if word in string_list`

Comment: And you are pring `file_name` with a sep of `word`? Couldn't you use the builtin `open(file_name, 'w')`? *(although maybe you were trying to use the `file` param of print, which would work)*

Comment: @CATboardBETA i already have a dataframe (from another analysis) which contains the list of strings I want to search for in text files (it has other information that isn't required for this piece of work)

Comment: why pandas?  This is unix `grep` capability,  search file contents

Comment: What does the text file looks like? Really one single word per line?

Comment: simply use `print()` to see values in variables. Especially `print(word)` and `print(string_list)`. You may have different values then you expect. BTW: It is `"print debuging"`

Comment: in `data` you have `apple` but you expect output with `Apple` - but `"apple" == "Apple"` gives `False` and you would need `"apple".lower() == "Apple".lower()` to get `True`. And the same problem you may have with your files - you have to convert all to `lower()` to compare correctly.

Comment: the text file isn't one word per line, it contains code, i was trying to use a simple example to explain the problem. I'm using a work machine and annoyingly dont have access to command line

Answer (score 0):

Use expanduser to get your path.  Use listdir to find all files in the directory.  Check if the filename endswith ".txt" if so then search the contents for the search phrase.  Use any to search a list in a list where any element found returns true. Split your text into words and remove empty string and \n

```
 import os

 search=['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
 search=list(map(lambda x: x.upper(),search))
 path=os.path.expanduser('~\python')
 for filename in os.listdir(path):
     if filename.endswith(".txt"):
          filename=path + "\\" +filename
          with open(filename) as fin:
             text=(fin.read())
             text=text.replace('>>',' ')
             mywords=text.split(' ')
             mywords=map(lambda x: x.upper(),mywords)
             mywords=[x.replace('\n','') for x in mywords if x]
             if any([x in search  for x in mywords]):
                 print(Fore.RED+filename)
                 print(Fore.BLACK)
                 print("{}\n{}".format(filename,text))
```